# Should I check whether a method is executed inside or outside of the method itself?

Tags: oop

I have a method which should be executed if a boolean is true.
The normal way to achieve this would be:

```
private void OneMethod() {
    if (ShouldExecute)
       OtherMethod();
}

private void OtherMethod() {
    Do Stuff...
}
```

Note that the varibale "ShouldExecute" is a global variable of the class.

But a colleague of mine recently started to put the `if` into the method itself.
So now it looks like this:

```
private void OneMethod() {
       OtherMethod(ShouldExecute);
}

private void OtherMethod(bool shouldExecute) {
    if (shouldExecute) {
        Do Stuff...
    }
}
```

He argues that the decision, whether the method should be executed, is a function of the method itself and thus should be a part of the method.

While i can see where he is coming from i still don't like his way. I think it just seems wrong and confusing.
If I see something like this:

```
var list = FilterList(list, otherParameter, yetAnotherParameter, shouldExecute);
```

I wouldn't read all of the parameters if they don't particually interest me. I would assume, that the list is somehow filtered by some parameters. Always.

But my argument "it feels wrong" is a pretty bad argument.
His way may clash with "Seperation of concerns" or the "Single responsibility principle" as well, which would be a stronger argument, but I'm not sure if that is the case.

But i really couldn't find any strong evidence for either of the two standpoints. And i don't really know what to search for, either...

So maybe someone here knows which way is more in line with the object-oriented programming paradigm.
And my goal is not to proof my colleague wrong, although i would be happy if were right, of course. :)
My goal is to find a good base on which we can create a policy for this case in our company's programming standards.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It depends on context, as usual. Passing a boolean "shouldExecute" seems rather weird, but some classes might be able to evaluate whether a particular function should be called(for example to check if a user is authenticated or sth). If you are forced to always call a method X together with a "shouldX" call, you should probably merge them. Adding a "shouldRun" parameter seems wrong, since if you already have that boolean you already know if you should run the method or not.

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer your concern describing a real-world case.

> You go to your workplace and a policeman stops you. And you tell him:
>   *hey agent, do I surpassed the maximum speed on this road?*

That policeman would think that you're laughable, because if you were aware of your infraction, why you did it? And, anyway, he would fine your anyway!

Usually rules are defined by who's not the target of the whole rule (excepting when we talk about *laws* which should be fulfilled by any person in your country).

For me, a method isn't responsible of knowing if it should be executed, but it's a responsibility of the caller, because the same method should be callable by other methods and those may have other conditions to decide if some method should be called or not.

Answer (score 0):

This way (the one your colleague proposes) you add a function to the call stack that basically does nothing if boolean value is false. The method should be called only if it has to be really executed to avoid a memory abuse.

About "separation of concerns" is your colleague to be in fault, as the called function shouldn't know "why" it has been called

Answer (score 0):

From the following code it seems that `OtherMethod` is already following `Single Responsibility Principle`, i.e it is doing things for which it is meant for. But use of `ShouldExecute` inside `OneMethod` is hiding some thing from the one who calls `OneMethod`.

```
private void OneMethod() 
{
    if (ShouldExecute)
       OtherMethod();
}
private void OtherMethod() 
{
    Do Stuff...
}
```

When a method expects some parameter the caller of that function knows that the parameter has some relevance in working of that function. So following code is more descriptive. But again if all the stuff `OtherMethod` is going execute only depends upon its parameter `shouldExecute` then why call the method itself. In such case previous code is better.

```
private void OneMethod() 
{
   OtherMethod(ShouldExecute);
}
private void OtherMethod(bool shouldExecute) 
{
    if (shouldExecute) 
    {
        //Do Stuff...
    }
}
```

Finally, this will be better, maintaining SRP as well as not hiding anything from the caller of `OneMethod`:

```
private void OneMethod(bool _bShouldExecute) 
{
    if (_bShouldExecute)
       OtherMethod();
}
private void OtherMethod() 
{
    Do Stuff...
}
```

Comment: Okay, that is a good point. I will keep that in mind, although i don't think that it applies to the case that we currently have (which is, of course, a bit more complex than my example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's sensible to have a parameter to determine whether the logic of a method is executed or not. As much as possible, a method should be considered a piece of logic that always carries out the same task (for different parameters). As suggested in [Clean Code](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882), if you have boolean parameters that significantly change the behaviour of a method, maybe it should be a different method.

As a rule of thumb, I would say that if the documentation ends up being something like "This method does X, unless parameter P takes value V, in which case it does Y" (maybe excepting null or empty values in some cases) it probably means that there should be different methods and the caller should be more explicit about what needs to be done.